# Issue with Stored Procedure with Crystal Reports and C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have an issue generating a crystal reports using a stored procedure.

This doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPEBalDeliveryAssn] 
    @Assn VARCHAR(50), 
    @cropseason INT

IF @Assn = 'ALL'  
BEGIN
    SELECT     
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_bsi, 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.reaping_code, 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_name, 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.delivered, 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.number_deliveries, 
        dbo.FarmerGroups.PROD_EST,        
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.CropSeasonsID
    FROM  
        dbo.FarmerGroups 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode ON dbo.FarmerGroups.BSI_CODE = dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_bsi                   
    WHERE
        dbo.FarmerGroups.CROP_SEASON = @cropseason 
        AND dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.CropSeasonsID = @cropseason                
    ORDER BY 
        dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.reaping_code
END
```

But this does

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPEBalDeliveryAssn] 
     @Assn VARCHAR(50), 
     @cropseason INT

    IF @Assn = 'ALL' AND @cropseason = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT     
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_bsi, 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.reaping_code, 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_name, 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.delivered, 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.number_deliveries, 
            dbo.FarmerGroups.PROD_EST,       
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.CropSeasonsID
        FROM  
            dbo.FarmerGroups 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode ON dbo.FarmerGroups.BSI_CODE = dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.farmer_pay_bsi                   
        WHERE
            dbo.FarmerGroups.CROP_SEASON = 1 
            AND dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.CropSeasonsID = 1                
        ORDER BY 
            dbo.vDelFarReapGrpCodeBsiCode.reaping_code
    END
```

I am not sure why having `@cropseason` doesn't work and having an actual 1 does.

Comment: Have you tested the stored procedure in a Query Analyzer so you can be sure it returns a value or data set?  Even if it does return a value, you should compare the values returned by both of your stored procedures and see if they differ in some way.  It might also be useful to update the question in some way that might help us see the returned values in some capacity, or at least how they may differ.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @cropseason = isnull(@cropseason,0)
```

Comment: @cropseason is never null as the value comes from drop down box, its either 1 or 2. I added this below the code but still no luck